# Структурная схема алгоритма

Tags: алгоритм

Помогите исправить ошибки вот в этом задании и доделать его: **Составьте структурную схему алгоритма подсчитывающую количество чётных целых чисел в диапазоне от А до В.** Заранее спасибо. =)

[image: Imgur]

Нужно убрать модификацию,но чтобы цикл остался Help одна из важных оценок в четверти.

Comment: Вот мы и нашли место воспитания индийских программистов
Такая проверка на чётность никуда не годится:

    x = int(x/2)*2)

Comment: @ Vladislav Pyatkov, а какая же тогда должна быть формула?

Comment: `x div 2 = 0`

Comment: @KoVadim, @Влад Алексеев ну ни *div*, а *mod* или *%* (x % 2 = 0) обычно пишут (*div* обычно обозначают целочисленное деление).

Короче остаток от деления 2 (очевидно для чётных он 0).

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov, Спасибо, но самое главное что я не могу сделать это подсчет четных целых чисел в промежутке. Как их подсчитать?

Comment: @Влад Алексеев вы не можете перебрать числа от A до B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

навожу на мысль - примем диапазон 1-3 - четных 1, 1-4 - четных 2, 2-3 - четных 1, 2-4 - четных 2.

```
вычисляем X=(В-А+1)/2. 
 - если Х без остатка - то вот твое кол-во четных
 - если Х с остаткам - смотри на концы диапазона :
                    А и В нечетные -то  кол-во - это целая часть от Х
                    А и В четные  -то  кол-во - это целая часть от Х+1
```

Да!!!! - это верно при условии что А и В тоже участвуют в подсчете четных чисел

А цикл то тебе зачем????

если честно ты схему в вопросе сам рисовал??

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Но как записать в алгоритме целую часть от х или от х+1? Так чтоли intx и intX+1?

Comment: А и В четные  -то  кол-во - это целая часть от Х+1   - маленько не правильно поняли запись - мы сначала получаем целое от X а потом уже прибавляем 1

Comment: хм ночь на дворе))) разницы то нет(

Comment: @Ale_x: можно проще: `B/2 - (A-1)/2`.

Comment: @Ale_x допустим числа 3 и 5 нечетные. Значит х = 1.5, а целая часть от х это 1, но как эту целую часть вычислить какой командой?

Comment: можно проще: B/2 - (A-1)/2.  и что это дает?

Comment: @Влад Алексеев  так нет никаких циклов. а единица - это если у тебя диапазон начинается на четное число и заканчивается четным - то количество будет на 1 больше

Цикл тебе зачем??? или это по условию нада цикл использовать??

Comment: Так вот в чем проблема, а как сциклом сделать? Или это невозможно?

Comment: @Влад Алексеев, а в чем проблема с циклом? Перебираете целые, каждое проверяете на четность (остаток от деления равен 0) и подсчитываете их число

     int i, k = 0;
     for (i = a; i < b; i++)
       if (i % 2 == 0)
          k++;

Просто нарисуйте соответствующие пару соответствующих такой программе прямоугольников, ромбик со стрелочками да/нет и шестиугольник как оператор цикла.

Вот и все.

Comment: Вы же сами нарисовали такой блок (в единственном числе) а своем вопросе. Я отталкивался только от нарисованных Вами фигур.

--

Если его не использовать, то очевидно он заменяется на прямоугольник

      i = a

потом, ромбик проверки условия цикла

      i < b

с выходящими стрелками **no** (в обход тела цикла) и **yes**  (к ромбику с проверкой на четность в теле цикла) и прямоугольником *после* схемы тела цикла 

      i = i + 1

со стрелкой к ромбику проверки условия цикла.

--

Уфф... Насколько же проще писать текст программы словами, чем описывать ими дурацкие блок-схемы.

Comment: @avp Все доступно и понятно объяснил! спасибо большое!